# How to use regular expression when choosing an XML node by XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to search for  XML nodes whose names look like "image*", i.e. start with 'image'.
My sample XML:

```
<a name="image.1">
  <b name="image.22" />
</a>
```

My XPath is /b[@name='image.22']. I want to write the seletion [@name='image.22'] in the form of using regular expression there. I've tried [@name='image.+'] but it doesn't work.

Please help.

Answer (score 6):

Use starts-with:

```
[starts-with(@name, 'image.')
```

Comment: Thanks Dewfy. It works for me. But how about a more complex seletion using regular expression?